# Unable to get PRIMARY_KEY violation response from SQL Adapter using worklight?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

I have MySql table with userID,Mobile,Password,Re-Password column where Mobile Column is my PRIMARY_KEY and i am inserting data into this from my SQL Adapter.

**SQLAdapter-impl.js**

```
function registration(mob_no,user_name,pass,re_pass){
    return WL.Server.invokeSQLStoredProcedure({
        procedure : "registration",
        parameters : [mob_no,user_name,pass,re_pass]

    });
}
```

**SQLAdapter.xml**

```
<procedure name="registration" />
```

**Registration.js**

```
function registration(mob_no,user_name,pass,re_pass){
    var invocationData = {
            adapter : "SQLAdapter",
            procedure: "registration",
            parameters: [mob_no,user_name,pass,re_pass]
    };
    WL.Client.invokeProcedure(invocationData, {
        onSuccess: getSecretDataOKReg, 
        onFailure: getSecretDataFAILReg
    });
}

function getSecretDataOKReg(response)
{   
    var bool=response.invocationResult.isSuccessful;
    console.log("Registration Operation Successfull :" +bool);
    if(bool)
    {
        saveRegistrationDetails();
        $("#pagePort").load(path + "pages/Login.html", function(){
            $.getScript(path + "js/Login.js", function() {
                if (currentPage.init) {
                    currentPage.init();
                }
            });
        });
    }
}

function getSecretDataFAILReg(response)
{
    alert("Unsuccess "+response);
}
```

My Problem is When i insert new data, Everything goes fine i get proper response and everything is "Happie Ending Story" but while i am trying to insert the same Mobile number along with different permo-combo data i get error

```
Procedure invocation error. Runtime: Failed to retrieve data with procedure : registration worklight.js:4673
WL.Logger.__log worklight.js:4673
PUBLIC_API.(anonymous function) worklight.js:4858
onInvokeProcedureSuccess worklight.js:7355
window.WLJSX.Ajax.WLRequest.WLJSX.Class.create.onSuccess worklight.js:3238
window.WLJSX.Ajax.WLRequest.WLJSX.Class.create.onWlSuccess worklight.js:3210
(anonymous function) worklight.js:947
window.WLJSX.Ajax.Request.WLJSX.Class.create.respondToReadyState worklight.js:1156
window.WLJSX.Ajax.Request.WLJSX.Class.create.onStateChange worklight.js:1094
(anonymous function)
```

I understand this may have arrived since i have tried to insert same primary key data in MYSql but how could i positively handle it and show alert or something to user stating you are already registered ? Is there any problem in my js file to identify SQL Error code which is cant see in error response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error has nothing wrong with Worklight here i think you should use Callback which return value back from MySQL.

```
function registration(mob_no,user_name,pass,re_pass,returnValue){
    var invocationData = {
            adapter : "SQLAdapter",
            procedure: "registration",
            parameters: [mob_no,user_name,pass,re_pass,returnValue]
    };
    WL.Client.invokeProcedure(invocationData, {
        onSuccess: getSecretDataOKReg, 
        onFailure: getSecretDataFAILReg
    });
}

function getSecretDataOKReg(response)
{   
    var bool=response.invocationResult.isSuccessful;
    console.log("Registration Operation Successfull :" +bool);
    if(bool)
    {
        saveRegistrationDetails();
        $("#pagePort").load(path + "pages/Login.html", function(){
            $.getScript(path + "js/Login.js", function() {
                if (currentPage.init) {
                    currentPage.init();
                }
            });
        });
    }
}

function getSecretDataFAILReg(response)
{   
    console.log("Check this here "+ response.invocationResult.resultSet[0].returnValue);
    alert("Unsuccess "+JSON.stringify(response));
}
```

and in your Stored procedure use returnValue as OUT parameter and use if and else condition.

Please find this SQL Stored Procedure for the same:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `loginAuthentication`(IN mob_no VARCHAR(45),IN user_name VARCHAR(45),pass VARCHAR(45),re_pass VARCHAR(45),OUT returnvalue INT)

BEGIN
       DECLARE no_of_records INT;

       SELECT COUNT(*) INTO no_of_records
       FROM tablename.registration 
       WHERE tablename.registration.mob_no=mob_no ;

       IF no_of_records = 1 THEN 
       SET returnvalue = 0; //Already exists one record with mob_no
       ELSE

       // Your INSERT QUERY

       SET returnvalue = 1;
       END IF;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Already refered IBM Worklight - Is it possible to call Stored Procedures with the Out parameter? but will try with suggestion you asked me.

Comment: Worklight adapters do not support the Out parameter.

Comment: Idan is right, its not working. Also, i soon gonna update this question.

Comment: @PawanAryan : Check select count (*) from projectname.tablename where projectname.tablename.mob_no = data.mob_no ... If it matchs returnvalue  which will be user as OUT becomes '1' since mob_no is primary key else insert will execute and simply return the returnValue.. now returnValue would be '0' since its in else part. Try it ask your project DBA to tweek the Stored procedure. It works fine with me...

Comment: Sure i have mailed him the same. Will try this as well

Comment: @Pawan Arya: Try this with your SQL Stored procedure. It will definetely work

Comment: I already Did. i can see your edited code and same we tried its working fine... just in Success Callback we are doing if(bool && returnVal==1) else if(bool && returnVal==1)

Comment: Good, it most of the time happens when SQL fundaments aren't clear. I had similiar problem once and got it resolved from SQL expert. Glad it help ur cause.